# Running in Android Eclipse Helios

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hello Im a newbie in Android and eclipse my question is,How I can Fix the problem when Im going to run my Android project only logoof Android was found in emulator, not a phone..

Comment: You need to explain your issue further if you want someone to help.

Comment: What have you done so far in your application?

Comment: 1st I installed SDK and JDK for the eclipse, and I already connect those in path.. I also finished coding in eclipse and when Im going to run my program, in emulator only "ANDROID" pop-up with a black background..

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to install your Android Phone's driver first . They are usually in the sd card of your Android phone . Open your Android phone in USB mode and install the drivers. Then you'll be able to see your phone while running your android application.

Comment: thanks.. anyway what if I want to see the output of my Android program in Eclipse by clicking the run button, but it shows nothing but only "Android".

Comment: thanks.. anyway what if I want to see the output of my Android program in Eclipse by clicking the run button, but it shows nothing but only "Android".

Comment: Yah you can see the ouput and the logs in "LogCat" of Eclipse .. Goto "Window" -> "Show View" -> "Other" -> "Android" -> "LogCat" . For it to work the program must be running in "Emulator" or the "Android Mobile".

Comment: thanks again.. :) still the emulator shows only black screen with "ANDROID".. is there something wrong with my emulator or the code that Ive done?

Comment: Anyway I solve the issue :)). I downloaded new sdk and installed it correctly.. thanks guys for the help..